# Find the Reverse of a recursion function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recursion

I have a recursion function as follows:

$$R(0) = 1$$

$$R(1) = 1$$

$$R(2) = 2$$

$$R(2n) = R(n) + R(n + 1) + n ,\qquad \forall n \gt 1$$

$$R(2n + 1) = R(n - 1) + R(n) + 1 ,\quad \forall n\ge 1$$

Now I want to find the reverse of this function. I know that first of all, I should solve the relation then after finding the function calculate the reverse. But the problem is that since the relations are different for even and odd numbers I cant figure out how to find a unique solution or even when I try to solve them separately, since the variables have coefficient it seems complicated.

For more clarification, here is an example, of how you can find the inverse of the Tower of Hanoi:

$$H_n = 2H_{n−1} + 1$$
$$= 2(2H_{n−2} + 1) + 1 = 2^2 H_{n−2} + 2 + 1$$
$$= 2^2 (2H_{n−3} + 1) + 2 + 1 = 2^3 H_{n−3} + 2^2 + 2 + 1$$
$$.$$
$$.$$
$$= 2^{n−1} H_1 + 2^{n−2} + 2^{n−3} + · · · + 2 + 1$$
$$= 2^{n−1} + 2^{n−2} + · · · + 2 + 1$$
$$= 2^{n} − 1.$$

Now the inverse is

$$\log_2(H - 1)$$

Comment: How do you want to handle $R(10)=R(17)=22$?

Comment: @Somos Those points are actually ones that I'm looking for. I want to solve the relations for odd and even numbers and from their inverses calculate the duplicate points. I'm not sure if this is the right way but at least I know that I need to solve the relations first.

Comment: The point is if $R(n)=22$, then you can't find a unique value for $n$.